# Node and Document method selection basis?

Tags: javascript, dom

Node creation methods like `createElement`, `createTextNode`, `createComment` is defined on the `Document` interface while Node insert/delete methods like `appendChild`, `removeChild` is defined on the `Node` interface.

document is just a type of Node.

Does someone know the history or advantage behind this?

Comment: It seems like bad form for a base class to have factory methods that create its subclasses, no?

Comment: Document isn't a base class. Node is. Since a Node cannot exist without a Document, and the DOM API is very stable (as far as new node types are concerned), I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

DOM-Level-1 :

> Interface Node
>
> ownerDocument :
>
> The Document object associated with this node. This is also the Document object used to create new nodes. When this node is a Document this is null.

So, the main advantage of having these creation methods in Document is to automatically handle this reference in the new node (btw this reference is specified as readonly).